# Don't show the "delete answer" button for the automatic flag raised when users delete their posts

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, deleted-answers, automatic-flags

When a user starts deleting answers, an automatic flag is raised for one of a answer the user didn't delete; one of the possible actions for the moderators is "delete answer."

> [image: screenshot]

It doesn't make sense. The flag is alerting the moderators that a user is probably vandalizing his own posts, maybe because rage-quitting; deleting a question the user didn't delete is not an action the moderators would normally take. It would make more sense to undelete a question that was already deleted, probably the one with the higher score.

The "delete answer" button should not be shown for an answer the user didn't delete. Alternatively, the "undelete answer" button should be shown for one of the deleted questions.